# Android Studio Emulator not working in windows 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My laptop Setup:

Windows 11 Pro 21H2 22000.132

11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11370H @ 3.30GHz   3.00 GHz

Android studio latest Atric Fox 2020.3.1 build

For me, everything was working perfectly with Windows 10 and then I updated my laptop to windows 11. And after that when I start my android studio and run build on Emulator after some time waiting windows throws an error as [image: .exe file Not responding]

and the full one is shown below image

[image: Emulator error]

```
My device windows features are
```

[image: Current windows features enabled]

I  didn't change anything in android studio settings and my laptop settings but still got issues with my emulator.

Help me to figure out the issue or resolve it. I searched a lot regarding this I didn't find any appropriate solution regarding this issue. But I found that issue mentioned [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/202188690 android emulator does not work on windows 11 (if we use hyper v) plz fix it) but priority is a little low as per google

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Yes windows 11 breaks android emulator on some Intel and AMD chips. The is currently no official fix for this yet however there is a fix from the open source community in the link below

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202188690#comment18